# White screen after Splash on android - ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

currently i'm developing an App with the Framework Ionic2 / Cordova.
The application is ready for the beta test and i uploaded it to the Google Play Store. In the release everything works realy good.

Today i tried to change some stuff in the code and recognized a problem, when i run the application from my pc on my phone.
After the splash screen there is a white screen showing up for about 30s !
Ich checked the device with the debugger and after the app is installed the "Device is ready" fires after 3s. For the whole rest of the 30s nothing is happening. After that the app shows up and everything is working like before.

I have already tried to build the app with --prod --release but it makes no difference.

So my first choice was to reset my project to an older git commit to fix the problem, but now in every! commit the screen is white for about 30s. I can go back like 10 commits and it still there.

I was thinking about an problem with the cordova plugins or something like that and that's why the problem occurs in every version now.

Could that be possible or someone of you has advice for me?

/edit: 
Intriguingly when i want to debug the app and run it with
ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs
it shows no error, the white screen after splash is still there, but it only lasts like 5 seconds

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? There quite a few posts about this exact issue and still no "Answered" questions.

Comment: no couldn't solve the problem. started a new project and copied the content. This solved the problem but i dont know why